# Can you have multiple realm object servers?

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

I just saw the Realm Mobile Platform. I'm curious what kind of redundancy is available outside of users having a full backup locally.

Can you have multiple Realm Object Servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to run multiple Realm Object Servers in various configurations for greater performance or reliability. This advanced functionality is part of the Enterprise Edition.

For the Developer Edition, you can run multiple Realm Object Servers but they all act independent of each other. For example you could split you user data across multiple servers with certain user groups using specific machines.